# Table cell link not working in Firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox

I have a table of three cells whose first and last one are hyperlinks and appear on hover.

It works perfectly but doesn't link in Firefox. I have no ideas why this could be.
Any ideas?

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1o9cgjvh/)

HTML:

```
<table id="contentTable">
<tr>

<td class="pad" id="padL"><a href="http://valsday.tumblr.com/post/19617801125"></a></td>

<td id="centralc">
<a href="http://valsday.tumblr.com/post/19617801125"><img src="http://31.media.tumblr.com/tumblr_m15n6nMuyS1qbdh3do1_500.jpg"/></a>
</td>

<td class="pad" id="padR"><a href="http://valsday.tumblr.com/post/19617801125"></a></td>

</tr>
</table>
```

CSS:

```
 #contentTable {
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 700px;
    border-collapse: collapse;
 }

 #centralc img, #centralc > img, #centralc > iframe {
    max-width: 500px;
    margin: 0 auto;
 }

 .pad {
     width: 100px;
     opacity: 0;
     filter: alpha(opacity=0);
     background-image: url('http://static.tumblr.com/cv6ot7o/pdanbhzio/pad.png');
     vertical-align: middle;

         -webkit-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
   -moz-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
     -o-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
        transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
 }

 #contentTable:hover .pad {
filter: alpha(opacity=100);
opacity: 1;
    }

 #padR {
     border-top-right-radius: 50px;
     border-bottom-right-radius: 50px;
 }

 #padL {
     border-top-left-radius: 50px;
     border-bottom-left-radius: 50px;
 }

 .pad a {
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: inherit;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
 }
```

Comment: There is nothing in the link to click. Add an onclick to the cells instead

Comment: Please don't use tables for anything else then tabular data. We don't live in the 90s anymore...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

height:100% works only if it has parent height set. this did the trick for me, it is dirty solution but gives you the idea, that you has to set height to all parent elements if you want to use height:100%. also you need to change .pad a to display:block, since inline elements can't have fixed height.

```
table, tbody, tr, td, a {
    height:100%;
}
```